# How to specify paths for different components in Apple-app-site-association

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I have a list of deeplinks that don't require a path. However, only one specific component requires a path. How do I format this?

```
   "applinks": {
    "details": [
        {
            "appIDs": [
              "xxx.prod",
              "xxx.demo", // Duplicate app IDS
              "xxx.development"
            ],
            "components": [
              {
                "/": "/help/*",
              },
              {
                "/": "/example/*",
              }
            ]
        },
        {
          "appIDs": [
            "xxx.demo" // Duplicate app IDS
          ],
            "components": [
              {
                "/": "/redirect/*"
              }
            ],
            "paths": [
              "/uni/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "YOUR_TEAM_#.XC.com.YOUR_APP_NAME",
                "paths": ["/mobileapps", "/MemberArea", "/membercoaching/questionnaire"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "YOUR_TEAM_#.com.YOUR_APP_NAME.internal",
                "paths": ["/mobileapps", "/MemberArea", "/membercoaching/questionnaire"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that the path is an array of separated controllers etc or areas of the website. If the user does not clink on a URL with that as the ending, they will go to the website instead of the app.